# install android-sdk on meteor - downloaded but error given upun install

Tags: android, node.js, meteor

I tried to install android sdk on Meteor here's what happend:

```
   meteor install-sdk android
   ✓ Found Android bundle
   ✓ A JDK is installed                          
   ✓ Found Android Platform tools                
   Installing Android Build Tools                

   events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
   Error: read ECONNRESET
      at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
      at Pipe.onread (net.js:558:19)
```

when I try to add platform to there's an error given that the android sdk is not installed, how do I fix it and have android platform on ?

```
   meteor add-platform android
   The Android platform is not installed; please run: meteor install-sdk android
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command at sudo mode i.e. `sudo meteor install-sdk android`.

I had the same issue this worked for me.

Comment: I'v also added sudo but still have the same problem